# Softwares/pre-requisites to be installed for developing Android application in Windows Vista Home premium?

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator

I am planning to develop a android app. Could you plz suggest the Softwares/pre-requisites to be installed for developing Android application in window vista home premium ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply go here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

and follow the step by step instructions to get going, following that I recommend watching the following videos (providing your and Android coding beginner of course)

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3&feature=plcp

and afterwards

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7F399983B3D570AA&feature=plcp